# Caching of passwords

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

I'm using Likewise to connect a Linux machine onto a Windows network. Doing so allows GUI access to the Windows domain through the network file navigator (Ubuntu 10.04 - Gnome).

However when this action is performed the account is locked out. It is like the password is cached somewhere, and when Linux tries to authenticate with the Windows domain it tries multiple times incorrectly so that the account is locked out.

Any ideas on how this information can be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Run `seahorse` (it may show up in the menus as **Passwords and Keys**) and erase it from there.